# Indication for potential mediation or moderating relationships

Tags: regression, spss, mediation, interaction

I want to run a regression with many variables. Besides the hypothesized direct relationships between IV and DV, there might be some moderating and mediating relationships (but I don't know which) that I want to determine.
I know how to test whether there is a moderating or mediating relationship between certain variables. 
Here is my question: However, how do I know whether there could be such relationships? I mean, under which circumstances can I assume such potential relationships? What is the indication that leads to testing such relationships?
I am using SPSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two broad ways to know:

1) Review of the literature.  The literature on your topic may reveal such relationships

2) Theory.  If you have an *a priori* theory that such relationships exist, that is, of course, a reason to suspect them.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Flom for your quick answer. I thought about it logically and also looked at the literature. Based on those two things I developed my model. 
But I thought there would be other indications from the output because my prof. told me to play around with the data and try things out. That is when I would find other relationships (mediation, moderation) than the ones hypothesized. The model in the end might then look different from the initial (hypothesized) model.

Comment: There are no really good signs that I know of for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two basic empirical models:  theory testing and theory building.  In the case of theory testing,  the a priori theory will dictate whether the intermediary variable is a mediator or a moderator.  To the extent that your professor is encouraging you to "play around, it seems to me that you are engaged in theory building.  In that case, there is no prior yardstick as to whether the intermediary is a mediator or a moderator.  Now mediators and moderators are two completely different types of intermediaries.  A relationship between an IV and DV will NOT exist without the mediator.  A relationship between an IV and DV will  exist in the presence of a moderator.